# Why I am unable to send message on WhatsApp?

Tags: flutter, dart, whatsapp

When I click <kbd>Contact with seller</kbd> it opens the webpage and displays this in the console:

```
Web page not available
The web page at whatsapp://send/?phone=923424627671&text=Hi%2C%20I%20am%20interested%20in%20the%20product%3A%0A%0AProduct%20Name%3A%20Electric%20%0AProduct%20Image%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Ffirebasestorage.googleapis.com%2Fv0%2Fb%2Fecommerce-1b43e.appspot.com%2Fo%2Fimages1677497513119374%3Falt%3Dmedia&type=phone_number&app_absent=0 could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

When I click the link it goes to the web page of WhatsApp and when I click <kbd>Continue to chat</kbd> it sends the message but in physical mobile it gives the above error. Is web view adding mandatory? And in the app when I click <kbd>Back</kbd> it shows the web page of WhatsApp for a moment but not permanently. Why? Can anyone solve this error? Here is my code:

```
String buildWhatsAppMessage() {
    String message = 'Hi, I am interested in the product:\n\n';
    message += 'Product Name: ${widget.productName}\n';
    message += 'Product Image: ${widget.url}\n';
    message += 'Product Price: ${widget.productPrice}\n\n';
    message += 'Please let me know more about it.';
    return Uri.encodeFull(message);
}
void launchWhatsApp() async {
    String phoneNumber = 'https://wa.me/${widget.phonenumber}?text=${buildWhatsAppMessage()}';
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(phoneNumber))){
        launchUrl(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
    } else {
        showDialog(context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Seller has no WhatsApp number'),
                    content: Text('Unfortunately, the seller does not have a WhatsApp account.'),
                    actions: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text('OK'),
                            onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                        ),
                    ],
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

```
RoundedLoadingButton(
    child: Text(
        'Contact with seller',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    controller: contact,
    resetDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    resetAfterDuration: true,
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    color: Colors.blue,
    successColor: Colors.blue,
    borderRadius: 10,
    elevation: 3,
    onPressed: _isAddToContactLoading ? null : () async {
        setState(() {
            _isAddToContactLoading = true;
        });
        launchWhatsApp();
        setState(() {
            _isAddToContactLoading = false;
        });
        _addCartController.success();
    },
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add mode externalApplication

```
   launchUrl(Uri.parse(phoneNumber),mode:
   LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

**also make sure**
A queries element must be added to your manifest as a child of the root elemen

```
  <queries>

    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
    </intent>



</queries>
```